# Are posthumously-released songs by XXXTentacion actually sung by him?

Tags: production

With the release of XXXTentacion's new album *SKINS*, I am a little suspicious about if the actual singer is by the artist himself. Sure, there are a lot of vocals that *X* did not release, in which his music label is undoubtedly going to take advantage of to avoid losses through the $10M deal. But, his songs seem so unnatural that makes me think it's not him. Secondly, with today's sophisticated technology (AI), you can literally manipulate a person's face, and it would seem realistic at face value. I am wondering if developers have found out to do the same with audio as well.

PS: It is not my intention to offend XXXTentacion's estate or his music label, and simply want to be fully aware about the subject matter. #LLJ

Comment: Interesting question, but may be hard to prove one way or the other.

Comment: @Angst Just found out that he was already working on this album prior to his assassination. I am guessing there will be lots of posthumous album releases until no original vocals left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [this review](https://www.nme.com/news/music/xxxtentacions-posthumous-album-skins-released-following-leak-2417677) and [this one](https://hiphopwired.com/788755/the-track-list-for-xxxtentacions-album-skins-reveals-kanye-west-is-the-only-guest-feature/) mention that XXXTentacion is the vocalist and that the only guest vocalist is Kanye West.

If the vocals somehow sound different, it could be that the tracks published were demo versions, possibly unfinished, or not recorded for the "master tape" before the artist's death.